# String of coordinates to array

Tags: java

I'm attempting to take in a string of coordinates and convert them to an integer array of arrays as seen below:

myLine (string):

```
1-2 9-5 4-5 3-6 5-9
```

desired output:

```
[[1,2],[9,5],[4,5],[3,6],[5,9]]
```

So far I have split the string by spaces to isolate each coordinate:

```
result = new int[5][2];    
String[] temp_split = myLine.split(" ");
```

This has given me each coordinate in individual arrays, however I'm unsure as to how to extract  each integer element and place it in an array

Where I am currently at:

```
for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < result[1].length; j++) {
        result[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(temp_split[i][j]);
            }
        }
```

That does not even give me close to my desired result.

Comment: You already know how to use `String.split()`.  Why not use it again?  Or why not split on both spaces and minus signs in the first place, and form coordinates from adjacent pars of the resulting strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track. However you seem to be trying to do too much all at once. I would recommend taking it step by step. So first we need to split the `String` into the pairs of co-ordinates:

```
String[] split1 = input.split(" ");
```

Then we can loop through that array and split each item:

```
String[] split2 = split1[i].split("-");
```

Finally you can obtain your result:

```
result[i][0] = Integer.parseInt(split2[0]);
result[i][1] = Integer.parseInt(split2[1]);
```

So the final solution would look like this:

```
String[] split1 = input.split(" ");

for (int i = 0; i < split1.length; i++) {

    String[] split2 = split1[i].split("-");

    result[i][0] = Integer.parseInt(split2[0]);
    result[i][1] = Integer.parseInt(split2[1]);
}
```

---

Alternatively if you wanted something shorter, you could split by both the space and - characters and do something like this:

```
String[] split = input.split("[ |-]");
for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i+=2) {

    result[i / 2][0] = Integer.parseInt(split[i]);
    result[i / 2][1] = Integer.parseInt(split[i + 1]);
}
```

however this is probably overly complex for this use case.

Comment: How are you using 'i' in this case above? Maybe my issues revolve around how to manipulate a 2d array.

Comment: Just by looping through the first `split1` array, I can post a full code sample if you would prefer?

Comment: Hate to bother you like that, but I would really like to see it in action (and not just selfishly for the answer), I really want to understand this manipulation.

Comment: Edited my answer!

Comment: I suppose I was just confused about the five entries because I only see that you are setting 2 above. The code is obviously working however.

Comment: Yes it was just meant as a guide! Glad you've got it working!

Comment: Thanks for having a good attitude and explaining. Take care.

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect situation to use streams.

- split on one or more spaces
- split each of those pairs on `-` and convert to a int
- return an array of each pair
- and return all the pairs as an array of arrays.

```
String s = "1-2 9-5 4-5 3-6 5-9";

int[][] pairs = Arrays.stream(s.split("\\s+"))
        .map(pair -> Arrays.stream(pair.split("-"))
                .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray())
        .toArray(int[][]::new);

System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(pairs));
```

Prints

```
[[1, 2], [9, 5], [4, 5], [3, 6], [5, 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

somting like that

```
String[] temp_split = myLine.split(" ");
int [][] result = new int[temp_split.length][2];
for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
  String[] temp_split2 = myLine.split("-");
  result[i][0] = Integer.parseInt(temp_split2[0])
  result[i][1] = Integer.parseInt(temp_split2[1])
}
```